# raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers) pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound:

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i had install docker and docker-compose.But when i am trying to build the image it shows the above error. but i already install docer-compose and the exact version it claims in the error. Too much frustrating moment for me as a beginner in docker world.

`bappi@bappi-pc:~$ sudo apt install docker-compose`
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
docker-compose is already the newest version (1.8.0-2~16.04.1).

but when i tried  docker-compose --version
in my terminal it shows

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'docker-compose==1.8.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to remove the installed `compose` and re-install using:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.1/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

as that is what in the [Docu](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)

you can see that is also a very old `compose` version, the current stable is `v1.24.1`

Comment: it works that way. I just changed the version to 1.8.0. And everything is working. But i had to install in the specific directory that i am working now. I don't know why it needed to install in the directory not the global.

Comment: change the `-o` part then